# get all absolute paths of files under a given folder

Tags: java, list, java-7, apache-commons, absolute-path

I need to hold in memory all absolute paths of file names under a given directory.

myDirectory.list() - retrieves String[] of file names only (without their absolute paths).

Don't want to use File Object since it consumes more memory.

Last thing - I can use apache collections etc. (but didn't find anything useful for that).

Answer (score 10):

```
String directory = <your_directory>;
File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();
for(File file : files){
  if(file.isFile()){
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
```

This works, and I gotta say I'm confused when you say you don't wanna use File objects, but whatever works, I guess.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. Using File object is much more memory expensive then just holding the string of path. Case I'll handle folder with 100K files I'm afraid of out of memory etc. So - I'm looking for a neat solution to get String[] of all absolute files paths within a folder

Comment: If you already know the root path and relative paths of your files and you're not willing to perform another iteration to concatenate those strings, and you're also not willing to use File objects due to afraid of running out of memory, you should probably break your array into smaller arrays and process them separately following the steps provided.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't `myDirectory` holds the directory of all those files?
If so, just combine the path in `myDirectory` with each of the cells in the array `myDirectory.list()` returns.

Comment: Thanks. you mean - do anther iteration on MyDirectory.list() and combine it to a new String[] ? is there something neater out of the box?

Comment: What type is myDirectory?

Comment: I'm confused here. How can a File object contain information about a directory?

Comment: Isn't file and directory represented in Java as File Object? ;)